# How to enable “remember me” checkbox in login forms by default?

Tags: wp-login-form

I have wordpress website and i want to enable "remember me" checkbox on login forms by default because lot of user would like to login all the time until they will delete cookies. If the user does not want to be remembered, they can just uncheck the checkbox.Even i tried plugin (don't remember plugin name) but that plugin starts crashing my website. Is there any code to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check this link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form

If you use `<?php wp_login_form( $args ); ?>` in the arguments array just make remember from false to true

Like the example: 'remember' => true,

Note that the default value is true.

Comment: I am using woocommerce login form. I used [Remember Me Controls](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remember-me-controls/) & [Remember Me](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-remember-me/) but nothing works. 

Any suggestion..